# Image uploading issue in MERN stack

Tags: reactjs, forms, axios, multer, mern

I am arslan chaudhry Mern stack develpore. I am an issue for the last 4 days. I am unable to upload images in the MERN stack.
I am using Axios in ReactJS for this purpose. I have created a state and then use it post request.
Like This:

```
const [FormInfo, setFormInfo] = useState({productName:"",image:""})
//function for setting state
  let names;
  const setInputsData = (e) => {
    names = e.target.name;
    setFormInfo({
      ...FormInfo,
      [names]: e.target.value,
    });
  };
const submiteDataNow = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const res = await axios.post("/Create_Post", FormInfo);
  };
FORM
        <form method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
         <input name="ProductName" onChange={setInputsData}/>
         <input type="file" name="images" accept="image/*" onChange={(e) => {
           FormInfo.images = e.target.files;}} multiple />
         <input onClick={submiteDataNow} type="submit" />
        <form />
```

But I am receiving an empty image object in the backend.
Like:

[image]

Dear seniors please also share code about how I can upload pics in NodeJS using multer.

Comment: Why do you mutate the state `FormInfo`?

Answer (score 1):

maybe because you are not setting state using callback setFileInfo instead youre setting it using the variable FileInfo . State should not be modified in this way

Comment: i don't understand.please explain more.

Comment: you should not mutate the state using first variable of useState it is just used to access the value and use it while second variable after comma is used to update the state